# Macro using Find function and returning cell position

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to realize a function with two inputs (sheetname, word) and returning the cell location of "word" in (row , column)
Here is the code for returning the row value

```
    Function RowFinder(sheet1 As String, word1 As String) As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range

    ' I know that the word is situated btw A and C
    Set rng = Sheets(sheet1).Range("A:C")
    Set rngFound = rng.Find("word1", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)

    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not found"
    Else:
        MsgBox "found"
        RowFinder = rngFound.row
    End If

    End Function

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call RowFinder("Feuil1", "A")
    End Sub
```

I didn't manage to find "A" in Feuil1 as mentioned in the code. each time I execute the code, I have the msg "not found". -I'm sure of having it -

Thanks for help!

Comment: try `rng.Find(What:=word1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)`

Comment: @simoco: I guess you meant `Word1` and not `"Word1"`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I've already updated my comment, you may refresh page to see it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it to look for "word1" (a string that says "word1") not the variable word1, remove the quotation marks. i.e.
rng.Find(word1, lookat:=xlwhole)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is anything within quotes will be considered as a string.

Change

```
rng.Find("word1"
```

to

```
rng.Find(word1
```